# What does "witness" refer to in Matthew 24:14?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, witness

> And this gospel of the kingdom shall be preached in all the world for a witness unto all nations; and then shall the end come. (Matt 24:14, KJV)

What does "witness" refer to in this verse? Is it a native believer, or any believer, or something else?

Comment: This question is perhaps a better candidate for http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *Thayer's Greek Lexicon,* the sense of witness in this passage is "that persons may get knowledge of something the knowledge of which will be good for their benefit" (http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3142&t=KJV)

So Jesus is saying that the gospel will pass on knowledge of sin and redemption to its hearers; it will provide the supporting knowledge, perhaps resulting in a conviction of the heart, that allows a sinner to come to God for salvation.

Answer (score 1):

In this verse, "witness" is not a person, it describes the purpose of the preaching.

An alternative translation [NIV] makes it clearer:

> "And this gospel of the kingdom will be preached in the whole world
>   *as a testimony* to all nations, and then the end will come."

(emphasis added)

http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:14